# How to check if .NET Core 2.1 assembly is built in Debug mode?

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops

I have an Azure Durable Function that I'd like to attach VS2019 debugger to. When I try this I get a message that the function has been built in release mode. However, my DevOps build pipeline uses configuration 'Debug'.

I have grabbed a copy of the dll that was built. How can I tell if this really is a debug or release dll? I've opened in Telerik JustDecompile but can't see any obvious indication.

Comment: Do you also have a  `.pdb` file for your `.dll`?

Comment: Yes I can see that the zip created by the DevOps build contains the pdp alongside the dll

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> dotnet core 2.1 assembly how to know if debug?

Since you could get all the dll files, you could create a console application, then reference this/those dll file. Debugging this console application, open the **Modules** window under the debugging mode (`Debug`->`Windows`->`Modules`):

[image]

As you can see, there is an option **Optimized**, if the referenced dll is a release dll, it will show as `Yes`, otherwise, it will show as `No`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you @Leo that worked! My next problem is to figure out why it has been built as optimised when the log from the devops build pipeline shows that the --configuration param was set to debug:" [command]"C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" build d:\a\1\s\Interfaces.Avaloq.Presentation.AzureFunctions\Interfaces.Avaloq.Presentation.AzureFunctions.csproj --configuration Debug"

Comment: @RobBowman, I am not sure if you have set something like: `<Optimize>true</Optimize>` in the project `Interfaces.Avaloq.Presentation.AzureFunctions.cspro`. If not, we may need to check the build log, to check if the dll is created in the debug folder. BTW, if above not help you, I suggest that you could open a new thread with some more details info for this problem, like the build log and build definition about this task.

Comment: I have posted a follow-up question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58448161/why-dotnet-core-assembly-built-optimised-when-configuration-parameter-set-to-deb