# Why dotnet core assembly built optimised when configuration parameter set to debug

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops, msbuild, yaml, azure-pipelines

I have a dotnet core durable functions app that gets built by an Azure DevOps build pipeline. The yaml file for this specifies "Debug" as the configuration parameter, as can be seen in the extract from the build log shown below:

```
[command]"C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" build d:\a\1\s\Interfaces.Avaloq.Presentation.AzureFunctions\Interfaces.Avaloq.Presentation.AzureFunctions.csproj --configuration Debug
```

However, the assembly that is built is "Optimized" which prevents me from attaching a debugger. I know this because I downloaded the zip created by the build then added a reference to the assembly following instructions here: [Great SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58435877/how-to-check-if-net-core-2-1-assembly-is-built-in-debug-mode)

The csproj file being built is as follows:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v2</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <LangVersion>8.0</LangVersion>
    <NullableContextOptions>enable</NullableContextOptions>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Base.Core.SharedKernel" Version="1.0.0.23885" />
    <PackageReference Include="FluentValidation.AspNetCore" Version="8.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="MediatR.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask" Version="1.8.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus" Version="3.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage" Version="3.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Http" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="1.0.29" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.2" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Interfaces.Avaloq.Application\Interfaces.Avaloq.Application.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Interfaces.Avaloq.Common\Interfaces.Avaloq.Common.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Interfaces.Avaloq.Infrastructure\Interfaces.Avaloq.Infrastructure.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Interfaces.Avaloq.Persistence\Interfaces.Avaloq.Persistence.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

The yaml for the build is:

```
trigger:
- develop
stages:
- stage: Build
  jobs:
  - job: Build

    pool:
      name: Hosted Windows 2019 with VS2019
      demands:
      - msbuild
      - visualstudio

    variables:
      solution: '**/*.sln'
      projects: '**/Interfaces.Avaloq.Presentation.AzureFunctions.csproj'
      testProjects: '**/*[Tt]esting*/*.csproj'
      buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
      buildConfiguration: 'Debug'

    steps:
    - script: |
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: Restore
      inputs:
        command: restore
        projects: '$(projects)'
        feedsToUse: config
        nugetConfigPath: nuget.config

    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: Build
      inputs:
        projects: '$(projects)'
        arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration)'

    - task: AzurePowerShell@4
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: 'Design Subscription (e73cbf58-ae70-454f-89dc-692d3882dbf4)'
        ScriptType: 'InlineScript'
        Inline: |
          Set-Location $env:AGENT_WORKFOLDER
          Get-ChildItem -Recurse
        azurePowerShellVersion: 'LatestVersion'

    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: Publish
      inputs:
        command: publish
        arguments: '--configuration Release --output $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
        projects: '$(projects)'
        publishWebProjects: false
        zipAfterPublish: true

    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      displayName: 'Publish Artifact'
      inputs:
        PathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
      condition: succeededOrFailed()

    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      displayName: 'Publish Artifact: ArmTemplate'
      inputs:
        PathtoPublish: Interfaces.Avaloq.Deployment
        ArtifactName: RGDeploy
```

Any ideas why the assembly is being built as optimised?

Comment: hmm, in the yaml - I think I see a case problem with the BuildConfiguration variable. Checking now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `--configuration Release` for the publish step